# "zstd: symbol lookup error: zstd: undefined symbol: POOL_joinJobs" error on Arch Linux when trying to install applications with package managers

Tags: arch, pacman-package-manager, zstd

After updating to the latest version of gnome 45 and the latest kernel, I'm encountering an error when trying to install applications on my Arch Linux system (using pacman, yay, paru or makepkg).

The error message I receive is as follows:

```
zstd: symbol lookup error: zstd: undefined symbol: POOL_joinJobs
```

This error seems to be related to the 'zstd' library. It appears when I attempt to install various applications using the package manager, and it's preventing me from installing new applications.

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but the problem persists:

1. I've updated my system using `sudo pacman -Syu` to ensure all packages are up-to-date.
2. I've reinstalled the 'zstd' package using `sudo pacman -S zstd` to make sure it's properly installed.

How can I resolve this issue?